# What does あと mean in つーか怖いしあとレア?

Tags: translation

> つーか怖いし**あと**レア

I don't understand how あと is used in this sentence. What does it mean?

レア should mean rare, right?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「あと」 is a common modern colloquial word meaning "in addition", "and also", etc.

And yes, レア means "rare".

You did not ask but I will say for others that 「つーか」 is the slangy (and very common as well) way of saying 「って言うか」 or 「と言うか」.  It roughly means "I mean", "or more precisely", "or rather", etc.